# Run script from within pyspark shell

Tags: python, pyspark

I can run my python+pyspark script from the unix command line by typing

```
pyspark script.py
```

But how do I run script.py from within the pyspark shell? This seems like an elementary question but I can't find the answer anywhere. I tried

```
execfile('script.py')
```

But I get an error which includes:

```
ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once
```

Comment: Try `subprocess.call`(https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call). My understanding is that `execfile` tries to evaluate the file in the same Python instance, whereas with the `subprocess` module you can spawn another instance of Python and PySpark, without any conflict.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. After making my code executable and adding a chmod, I am able to run the code this way. But after it runs, I cannot access the variables in the code. So it is nearly the same as running 'pyspark script.py' in unix.

Comment: Yes, you would not have access to the variables unless you pipe them into another variable or persist them in some data structure. `subprocess` will only help you invoke another spark program. You could try something similar to `subprocess.Popen` with `stdout=PIPE`

Comment: I'm curious as to which version of Spark you're using such that you could execute $ pyspark script.py. In my case: "Running python applications through 'pyspark' is not supported as of Spark 2.0."

Comment: My question was pre-Spark 2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could the error come from `script.py` trying to create a new SparkContext variable?

When you launch the pyspark interactive client it usually says :
`SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext.`

If your script file contains `sc = SparkContext()`, maybe try commenting it.